# Using "if else" inside a function gives unexpected keyword_end error

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I have defined a function which looks like this:

```
def putValAndmyBool val mybool
    if mybool
        puts val + "true"
    else
        puts val + "false"
    end
end
```

It gives the following error:

> SyntaxError: (irb):101: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ';' or '(irb):107: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
>           from K:/Ruby22-x64/bin/irb:11:in `'

But when I defined following function, it runs successfully. The reason I tried doing this is I thought something in line puts val + "true" is causing the issue.

```
def addbool val
    puts val + "true"
end
```

Comment: You are missing a comma `,` between the method's arguments `val` and `mybool`

Comment: Readers don't know the contents of the line IRB has labelled 101. When reporting errors please indicate where the exception was raised as well as the exception itself.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: point taken. It seems to me asking questions for a naive person is tougher on this site. You get downvoted for it. Although I  started learning Ruby few hours back.

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes. Even high-rep members get them. Most downvoters like to remain anonymous, so you'll never find out the reason for a downvote. I rarely downvote, but when I do I always give the reason in a comment. If you'd like help to improve working code, have a look at SO's sister-site, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What parameter are you passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incorrect

```
def putValAndmyBool val mybool
```

I suppose should be

```
def putValAndmyBool val, mybool
```

Comment: Oh! My bad... I am just on control structures in the book. I think I started experimenting too soon. Thanks!